# Grouping content by Years (For eg Archive 2014-2015 or Archive 2014-16)

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I want to group my content type to group by years in views, for example `Archive 2014-2015` or `Archive 2014-16`. How can I get this groupings?

```
Archive 2013-2014
-COntent 1
-Content 2
-Content 3

Archive 2015-2016
-COntent 1
-Content 2
-Content 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The key challenge you'll face here is that neither Views nor Date modules provide aggregation options for date-based fields.

This can be solved by using the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module. It adds a nice little check-box that allows you to group dates by a custom formatted string, as shown in this example also:

[image]

In the above example, the **custom date format** is set to "M Y" (which translates to Oct 2015 for example), and the box for "Use SQL to format Date" was checked. This is the only configuration needed.